# UIView in UIScrollView won't stretch full width

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout, storyboard

I have a view controller with a UIScrollView (see in red below) which     contains a UIView (in blue). I added UIView constraints which should make it stretch full width (see image 2) but don't. I've created UIScrollViews/UIViews in a similar manner before and they've worked. Could someone help me understand what I'm missing?

## Screenshot

[image: Screenshot emulator]

## Constraints

[image: Constraints]

## View Structure

[image: View structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a width constraint from the UIView to the top View.